# Animation issue jQuery CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I just want to make an exit animation but I've got problems with the text inside the box which I want to hide.

```
$(".dropdown").click(function () {
    var dropdownC = $(this).find(".dropdownc");
    var dropdownUl = $(this).find("ul");

    if (dropdownC.css("visibility") == "visible") {
        dropdownC.removeClass("comein").addClass("comeout");
        var hide = function () {
            dropdownC.addClass("hide");
        };
        setTimeout(hide, 300);
    } else {
        dropdownC.removeClass("hide").removeClass("comeout").addClass("comein");
    }
});
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zaLdr9mj/). Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `display: block / none` instead of `visiblilty: visible / hidden`

https://jsfiddle.net/dabvkmrL/1/

Comment: What kind of answer is this?